# How to edit build.prop without root and without custom recovery?

Tags: adb, motorola-droid, motorola, verizon

I have an old Motorola-Verizon phone. Since it is a Verizon exclusive model, they didn't left any chance of rooting phone, unlocking bootloader or installing custom recovery. So my question is **Is it possible to have build.prop edited in these circumstances?**

I have searched everywhere and tried almost everything but could not have the job done. Every time some adb command is rejected by an indefinite `<waiting for device>` printed on the command-line or it just reboots to get back normal. No change.

My phone details if they are relevant:

- Phone: Motorola Droid Turbo 2
- Model : XT1585 (Kinzie)
- OS: Nougat 7.0

Another thing to mention is there is another phone sold by Motorola outside US i.e. **Moto X Force** which is essentially the same device without Verizon and Droid logos on it. And I can confirm that it is perfectly bootloader-unlockable. If it is helpful.

Comment: I don't understand the intent here to change build.prop. What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: not just for a particular intent but mainly because of some display tweaks like 270 degrees rotation and killing off navigation bar etc.All of this stuff can be done by editing build.prop and just looking for the way I can edit it.

Comment: You do not need to kill navigation bar. You can setup Immersive mode using an automation app which would universally hide your navigation bar. As for 270 degree rotation, you can use this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bong.android.androidlock&hl=en

Comment: But it shows up when I swipe up from the bottom edge. I just wannt it to completely disappear

Comment: You can hide it like the way you want using this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xda.nobar&hl=en_IN But you must setup ADB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to have build.prop edited in these circumstances?

Unfortunately, no. Build.prop rests in the system partition and that partition is mounted as read-only by the Android. To edit the file, the partition has to be mounted in read-write mode, which requires root privileges which you are sure you cannot gain on this device.

That said, some of the properties can be altered using setprop tool through adb. Mostly the ones starting with the prefix *persist* can be changed successfully and the effect be observed in real time. While read-only properties may show successful result after their value altered using setprop, the effects would not be seen.